# How to create session in Next js project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using **Next js** to create my project, and I have created a custom signup form in it. In here I'm getting email and password of the user and them I'm sending an otp on user's email. after varifieng user I want to store his data.

I want to use session for this, but I'm not getting any good way to create session in Next js
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to solve this is used browser cookie to store the token, as cookies allows expiry option.

```
let today = new Date();
today.setHours(today.getHours() + 1);

document.cookie = "User_Token=" + userTokenValue + ";expires=" + today + 
";domain=https://www.example.com";
```